# having 2 mysqli errors which causes data to not be inserted

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 //connected to db

if (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $_POST['teacherusername'];

}

        $sql = "SELECT TeacherId FROM Teacher WHERE (TeacherUsername = ?)";

        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$_SESSION['teacherusername']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $record = $stmt->fetch();
        $teacherid = $record['TeacherId'];
        $stmt->close();




        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

        {

        $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_SESSION['durationChosen']);

        $insertsql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql);

        for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i) {
            $sessid = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
            $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

            $insert->bind_param("sssssssss", $sessid, $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
                             $_SESSION['textWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
                             $_SESSION['module'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);

            $insert->execute();

           if ($insert->errno) { echo "Error in insert: $insert->error<br>\r\n"; }

            $insert->close();
        }


        }
```

UPDATE:

The previous errors have been fixed, but I am now getting 4 warnings which are displayed below:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in /web/stud/.../Mobile_app/insertsession.php on line 177

Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() [mysqli-stmt.execute]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in /web/stud/.../Mobile_app/insertsession.php on line 179

Warning: main() [function.main]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in /web/stud/.../Mobile_app/insertsession.php on line 181

Warning: mysqli_stmt::close() [mysqli-stmt.close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in /web/stud/.../Mobile_app/insertsession.php on line 185

As that mysqli is now inserting data into the database, do I deal with these warnings or shall I leave them alone?

PROBLEM IS SOLVED, FOR FUTURE VIEWERS PLEASE LOOK AT DAVE RANDOM'S ANSWER

Comment: You are not doing any error checking, so it's no wonder the code breaks when the query fails. Check out the examples in the manual for how to do proper error checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this line at the end of your loop and it should work:

```
$insert->close();
```

This will work *if* you don't still have an unclosed statement from code that is executed before the code you show. You *must* close the previous statement before another can be executed.

See [`mysqli_stmt::close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) for more information.

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
//connected to db

$sql = "
  SELECT TeacherId
  FROM Teacher
  WHERE TeacherUsername = ?
";

if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

// Bind parameter for statement
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['teacherusername']);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

// This is what matters. With MySQLi you have to bind result fields to
// variables before calling fetch()
$stmt->bind_result($teacherid);

// This populates $teacherid
$stmt->fetch();

// Close the statment
$stmt->close();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

{

    $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_SESSION['durationChosen']);

    $insertsql = "
      INSERT INTO Session
        (SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room)
      VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ";
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

    for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i) {

        $sessid = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
        $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

        $insert->bind_param("sssssssss", $sessid, $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
                     $_SESSION['textWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
                     $_SESSION['module'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, I am not getting any errors which is great but it is not inserting any data into the database. The query is definetly correct, I just don't know why it isn't inserting any data?

Comment: @user1421767 Add these lines between the `$insert->execute();` and `$insert->close();` calls: `if ($insert->errno) { echo "Errors in insert:<br>\r\n"; foreach ($insert->error_list as $error) { echo "Error {$error['errno']} (State = {$error['sqlstate']}): {$error['error']}<br>\r\n"; } }`

Comment: When I added the line in you have gave me, it has given me 2 more errors. I have added these errors in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the error_list was only added in 5.4. Replace the lines from my previous comment with this: `if ($insert->errno) { echo "Error in insert: $insert->error<br>\r\n"; }`

Comment: This is the message I am recieving: `Error in insert: Column 'TeacherId' cannot be null` I will show you my whole code in my question. What I am trying to do is retrieve the teacher's id and then insert it into the Session table with the other values.

Comment: clearly you are trying to insert a null value into the table. Fix that and it should work fine.

Comment: @Brendan But thats the point it shouldn't be null, it should retrieve the teacher's username. I don't get how come it is null

Comment: How are you getting the teachers name? From the  database? A form? Show that relevant code.

Comment: @user1421767 See edit above. `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()` is the main reason I hate MySQLi and use PDO instead.

Comment: @DaveRandom I will test your code now, I will use PDO in future but I have to use mysqli because my version of php is 5.2.13 (university's server)

Comment: @DaveRandom Ok it has inserted the data into the databae but it does give me 4 warnings. Do i deal with the warnings or leave them as they are as that it is inserting the data? I updated the warnings in the question.

Comment: @DaveRandom It is ok, I figured out how to remove the warnings, I put the query into the for each loop. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @user1421767 PDO has been available since PHP 5.1, the server administrator just needs to enable it. Kindly inform your university from me that they **need** to update their PHP version to at a minimum the latest in the 5.3 branch. There have been numerous security fixes and performance improvements in the last 2 1/2 years (5.2.13 was released 02/10) and many, many features are not available in 5.2 (namespaces, closures, class constants and more), plus from 5.3 PHP has a native MySQL driver instead of using libmysql. This is a 10 minute job and in a teaching establishment there is no excuse.

Comment: @user1421767 Glad you figured it out :-)